# Software License Agreement on download/on update

Tags: licensing

I've been looking through the other questions around Software Licensing, but I couldn't find a fitting answer. Is showing a license agreement on download of a piece of software enough, or does it have to be shown on start and after an update as well to be valid?

Comment: IMO legal stuff is (nearly) always too localized or broad if asked generally. I doubt it is written in any law explicitly, so you probably need an actual ruling in a case within the jurisdiction area you are interested in.

Comment: hmm... my agreement is governed by the law of the Netherlands so I guess I'll have to figure out what the actual ruling in the Netherlands is

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is too long for a comment, but I think its worth of sharing.

I'm from Poland and I am quite sure that a judge could rule whatever he wanted in such case, and then maybe a ruling guidance would be made by Supreme Court. This is generally how things work here AFAIK. I.e. no US-style precedence law.

**I think you need a local lawyer opinion on this to be sure.**

Some of the approaches I saw. League of Legends client asks to agree to two documents every update. I think one is license and one is ToS. But I think I never saw any other software doing this upon every single actualization, unless the actualization was performed by external program, e.g download new version and fire up executable, which often is case with drivers. The opposite is when program "internally" updates itself, I think for example chrome or some games do it like that. They don't ask anything. But maybe they just don't care.